# Slicing nodes within array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list, slice

When I first select two options from the 2nd select menu, the array becomes is populated with those two selections. What I want is for the second selected option to replace the first, so even if I do begin by selecting two options from the 2nd select menu, the array's length will remain at one, dynamically changing between those selections. I hope you understand. Thanks for any help. I know I could just make it one function and this problem wouldn't exist but for my use of it I can't do that.

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
var array = []
        
function myFunct1() { 
  var one = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
  array.splice(0, 1, one);
  console.log(array);
        }
        
function myFunct2() {
  var two = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
  array.splice(1, 1, two);
  console.log(array);
        }
```

```html
<select id = 'select1' onchange = 'myFunct1()'>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value = 'Dog'>ONE</option>
        <option value = 'Cat'>TWO</option>
        <option value = 'Bear'>THREE</option>
        </select>
    
        
    <select id = 'select2' onchange = 'myFunct2()'>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value = 'Dog'>ONE</option>
        <option value = 'Cat'>TWO</option>
        <option value = 'Bear'>THREE</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: What would happen if `array = ["One","Two"]` and `TWO` is pressed. Array should change to `["Two","One"]` or remain `["One","Two"]`

Comment: Right, but my issue occurs when you press two twice.

Comment: You want array to remain. `["One","Two"]` or change to this `["Two","One"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`Array.prototype.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add value at first place. You can check if element exists in array 
using `includes()`.
And instead of creating two functions you can create same function and pass different parameters to it.

```js
var array = [];
        
        function myFunct(val){ 
            if(!array.includes(val)) array.unshift(val);
            console.log(array);
        }
```

```html
<button onclick = 'myFunct("One")'>ONE</button>
        <button onclick = 'myFunct("Two")'>TWO</button>
```

If you want to replace the new value with first value use this code

```
function myFunct(val) {
     array.unshift(val);
     array = [... new Set(array)];
     console.log(array); 
}
```

#### Update:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');
var array = [];
let sel1 = false;

function myFunct1() { 
  var one = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
  if(array.length === 1 && !sel1) array.unshift(one);
  else array.splice(0,1,one);
  console.log(array);
  sel1 = true;
}

function myFunct2() {
  var two = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
  array.splice(sel1, 1, two);
  console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: But what if instead of buttons that always push 'One' and 'Two' I'm using select menus that I want it to remember and replace the option from each select menu, but by this method it wouldn't replace unless you reclicked the same option.

Comment: @Harper Creek You didn't answered my question _What would happen if `array = ["One","Two"]` and `TWO` is pressed. Array should change to `["Two","One"]` or remain `["One","Two"]`_?

Comment: I mean in the example it becomes  ["Two","One"]? Are you asking if that matters for what I'm trying to do? I guess it doesn't. I may be more convenient if Two stays at the 1 spot.

Comment: @Harper Creek Ok now please **edit** your question what help you need more

Comment: @Harper Creek I have updated the code. Tell me if there is still some problem

Comment: I appreciate the help. The issue with the updated code is that it replacers the selected option of the second select menu when you choose a selection from the first. What I need is that when you select from the first select menu, it doesn't replace the selection from the second from the array, it just bumps it to the 1st position, along with my first condition, that if you were to select two options from the second select menu without ever touching the first select menu, it would not bump the first selection from 0 to 1, and just replace it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189705/discussion-between-maheer-ali-and-harper-creek).

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
var array = [];
        
function myFunct() {
  if(array.indexOf('One') === -1 ) { array.unshift('One') ; }    
  console.log(array);
}
        
function myFunct2() {
  if(array.indexOf('Two') === -1 ) { array.push('Two') ; }
  console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<button onclick = 'myFunct()'>ONE</button>
<button onclick = 'myFunct2()'>TWO</button>
```